# How to send only updated values of a row?

Tags: postgresql, json, event-notification

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION notify_col()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
    BEGIN
        PERFORM pg_notify('channel', row_to_json(NEW)::text);
        RETURN NEW;
    END; 
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

I'm trying to listen on *channel*, for any updates in the row (transformed with `row_to_json()`). But I want `pg_notify()` to send only updated values of the row, not the whole row.
Do I need an `if` condition or is there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Why would you assume that there is always exactly *one* updated column, never more, and never none? And please *always* declare your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sends a JSON array of columns that actually changed, with their new value:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION notify_col()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN
   PERFORM pg_notify('channel'
                   , (SELECT json_agg(n)::text
                      FROM   json_each_text(to_json(OLD)) o
                      JOIN   json_each_text(to_json(NEW)) n USING (key)
                      WHERE  n.value IS DISTINCT FROM o.value));

   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER tbl_upd_aft
BEFRE UPDATE ON tbl
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN (OLD IS DISTINCT FROM NEW)  -- optional
EXECUTE procedure notify_col();
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=1a0e56dfd1488191a7821acbb9fa4bc8)*

If works by converting `OLD` and `NEW` to JSON and expanding each to a set of key/value pairs. Then join on the key and only keep columns (now rows) that actually changed. Finally aggregate into a JSON array.

Note the `WHEN` condition to the trigger. Updates that do not actually change anything don't fire the trigger. (So the trigger is guaranteed to process actual changes.)

If there can be more triggers consider an `AFTER` trigger to only report what's actually changed. And reconsider the `WHEN` condition if triggers might add changes - which would circumvent this condition.

Related:

- [Is it possible to dynamically loop through a table's columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49742016/939860)
- [Trigger with multiple WHEN conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18360493/939860)
- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12632129/939860) (about empty updates)

Aside: consider this [note in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE):

> `array_to_json` and `row_to_json` have the same behavior as `to_json` except for offering a pretty-printing option.